# Join multiple rows into a single column

Tags: sql, join

I have to create a report based on 2 files, table1 is the master file, table2 is an Attributes file. Is possible to join these two files and create the below resultant table.

Table1:

| ID | NUM |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |

Table2:

| ID | NUM | ATTR | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | ATR1 | BLUE |
| A | 1 | ATR2 | GREEN |
| A | 1 | ATR3 | RED |
| B | 2 | ATR1 | WHITE |
| B | 2 | ATR2 | PINK |
| B | 2 | ATR3 | RED |

Resultant table:

| ID | NUM | ATTR1 | ATTR2 | ATTR3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | BLUE | GREEN | RED |
| B | 2 | WHITE | PINK | RED |

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are looking for a PIVOT.  How complex it is depends on your RDBMS.  Depending on you are generating your report, you may want to just handle this in your tool.

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregation. You can do:

```
select
  a.id,
  max(a.num) as num,
  max(case when b.attr = 'ATR1' then b.val end) as attr1,
  max(case when b.attr = 'ATR2' then b.val end) as attr2,
  max(case when b.attr = 'ATR3' then b.val end) as attr3
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.id = b.id
group by a.id
```